# Use will_paginate gem with an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails application i defined an array that i would like to use with the will_paginate gem.
The array (arr) looks like this:

```
["/uploadsave/Emmanuel_4.png", "/uploadsave/Emmanuel_5.png", "/uploadsave/Emmanuel_6.png"..
```

In my controller i tried:

```
@arrems = arr.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8)
```

But that provoces an error:

```
undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x75fb940>
```

So what can i do?

Comment: Should i delete my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `require 'will_paginate/array'` at the top of any controllers that will use array pagination.